# macos wakes up from sleep very slowly when internet connection is also slow

Tags: macos, catalina

I have the latest macos (BigSur or Catalina I think) on a new Macbook Air.
When I have poor wifi reception (e.g. I go to garden and I'm too far from the rooter) or if the internet connection is slow then when I open the lid of the mac I see the screen later than normally and the keyboard and mouse are unresponsive for a minute - sometimes even mac notices that and asks if I would like to connect a bluetooth keyboard.

Everything is normal when I'm on a normal internet connection.
SO basically, WTF? I heard that Apple introduced some software that validates hashes of running programs before they are allowed to run, and it does it over the internet. So it sounds like this is the issue.

Any solutions to that (besides speeding up the connection)?

EDIT: OK, now I know, this is called notarization and not only I have such issues: https://sigpipe.macromates.com/2020/macos-catalina-slow-by-design/

Are there any workarounds?